# Panda If statement on repeating rows

Tags: python, pandas

this may be an easy question and i am over complicating this if statement, please help if you can.
Here is scenario: Updated with template

```html
Input:
Customer|Product|Product2
123|A|
234|B|
123|C|
345|D|

Expected Output:
Customer|Product|Product2
123|A|Multiple
234|B|B
123|C|Multiple
345|D|D
```

Failed attempt

```html
df["Dups"]=df.duplicated("Customer",keep=False)<-create new col to find duplicates

df.loc[df.Dups] <- view filtered df

df.loc[df.Dups]["Product2"] <-view filtered column
```

not sure how to replace filtered results. i tries masking and .str.replace, no luck

Comment: Please provide an example table with `Product A, B, C, Multiple`, to illustrate what you are trying to achieve, and how you call the function `Product2`. The error is likely thrown from the line `CP=row.repeatcustomer` but your question formulation is lacking much detail.

Comment: Hi.. Welcome to SO, please provide minimal-reproducible-example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey there welcome to SO, I think you're approaching the problem in the wrong way, you don't need to loop as pandas takes advantage of vectorised operations across columns/indices. as for your error, the series you've passed in the function doesn't have that column. Are you able to add your source data ?

Comment: @Datanovice ok thanks, ill try to redo, how can i make a new colume that has true/false or even just the value counts, i tried sheet3["CustomerRepeat"]=sheet3["Customer"].value_counts() but just get NaN for all rows

Comment: @Datanovice, i got it to filter correctly now (updated above). looks like i dont need the if statements. but not able to replace, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution for anyone else who runs into this, product2 no longer required:

```html
df["Product"]=df["Product"].cat.add_categories('Multiple')
df["Dups"]=df.duplicated("Customer",keep=False)
df.loc[df.duplicated("Customer",keep=False),["Product"]] ="Multiple"
```